# what does "Read Swap Header failed: Success" mean?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, swap

I'm trying to install Arch Linux (from the 2014-04-01 snapshot). I've made a swap file and tried to `swapon` it, but I got an error(?) message I don't understand.

I've executed

```
fallocate -l 512M /mnt/sda2/swapfile
chmod 600 /mnt/sda2/swapfile
swapon /mnt/sda2/swapfile
```

and the output is

```
swapon: /mnt/sda2/swapfile: read swap header failed: Success
```

and I have `:(` at the end of my command line.  So did it succeed or fail? Is this not how to set up a swap file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is this not how to set up a swap file?

I think you missed a step in between `chmod` and `swapon`:

```
mkswap /mnt/sda2/swapfile
```

As for the oxymoromic error...

> swapon: /mnt/sda2/swapfile: read swap header failed: Success

What this literally means is there's a bug in the `swapon` code, but not necessarily one related to its primary functioning.

C library functions often make use of [errno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno), a global variable that stores an error code.  The function itself will return a value indicating an error occurred (any error), and the exact nature of that error will be stored in `errno`.  The idea is that if you get an indication of an error, you can then check the value of `errno` to see exactly what it is.

There's also a `strerror()` library function that will take an errno value (they're integers) and return a human language string relating to it.  One of those is `Success`, which corresponds to an error code of 0 (i.e., no error).

So when you see something like this, it indicates a mistake such as:

- Getting an error, then calling another function (successfully) which resets errno to 0 behind the scenes, then using errno to determine the specifics of the error you got before you called the second function.

And/or

- Passing `strerror()` a variable that was supposed to have been assigned the value of errno at some point (to prevent the previous mistake from happening) but wasn't.

Comment: You get two upvotes if I could - the `mkswap` and `errno`.